# Python - Error when attempting to control inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, nameerror

I'm trying to write a rock-paper-scissors exercise in Python. The core functionality of the game is there. However, I'm trying to write an output for when the user inputs something other than "rock", "paper", or "scissors." As you can see from the code below, the else statement at the end of the game should catch if the user entered something other than one of the three expected answers. If they do, they should get "Something went wrong!" as an output.

Here is the program code:

```
print ("Rock...")
print ("Paper...")
print ("Scissors")

player_one = input("Player One, make your move! ")

player_two = input("Player two, make your move! ")

if player_one == "rock" and player_two == "paper":
    print ("Player Two Wins!")
elif player_one == "rock" and player_two == "scissors":
    print ("Player One Wins!")
elif player_one == "paper" and player_two == "rock":
    print ("Player One Wins!")
elif player_one == "paper" and player_two == "scissors":
    print ("Player Two Wins!")
elif player_one == "scissors" and player_two == "rock":
    print ("Player Two Wins!")
elif player_one == "scissors" and player_two == "paper":
    print ("Player One Wins!")
elif player_one == player_two:
    print ("Time Game!")
else:
    print("Something went wrong!")
```

However, I get the following error in PowerShell when I respond with something other than "rock", "paper" or "scissors" for my player_one response. For instance, when I type "rocks", I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rpsbasic3.py", line 5, in <module>
    player_one = input("Player One, make your move! ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'rocks' is not defined
```

I've been messing with it for a while and am at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're on python 2, either upgrade to python 3, or replace:

```
player_one = input("Player One, make your move! ")

player_two = input("Player two, make your move! ")
```

With:

```
player_one = raw_input("Player One, make your move! ")

player_two = raw_input("Player two, make your move! ")
```

Comment: Wow -- such a simple answer to this problem. Thank you very much for pointing the error out to me.

I seriously had no idea that running a program in PowerShell with "python filename.py" ran it in Python2, whereas typing "py filename.py" ran it in Python3.